# Dynamic selector for on click event acting strangely after 2 events?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Not sure how best to describe this but I'll try and put in some context. I'm very new to both Javascript am still a beginner when it comes to PHP so please point out any issues you see - always willing to learn!

With that said, here's what I'm doing

- I've got a basic php page that uses AJAX to update a table on the click of a div (either .todo or .completed)
- The AJAX returns an array of the item that's been updated, I use this to pull the itemText, and the itemNo and append or prepend a div with the information inside it.
- Items clicked that are .todo are slid up and then added as .completed, and .completed on click are restored as .todo.

The issue is, if I click a .todo item, it is removed using slideUp and then prepended as .completed, no issues. However if I then click on the new .completed item to restore it as a .todo, a COPY is appended and the original remains.

I'm not quite sure what to do about this, any help is really appreciated.

**My JS**

```
$('#needToDo').on("click", ".todo", function() {

var itemNo = $(this).attr("id");

var updateQuery = "UPDATE items SET done=1 WHERE itemNo = " + itemNo;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "toDoProcess.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { query: updateQuery, itemNo: itemNo },

        success: function(resultArray){
            if(resultArray != ""){
                var itemNo = resultArray[0]['itemNo'];
                var itemText = resultArray[0]['itemText'];
                $('#' + itemNo).slideUp(function(){
                    $('#completedItems').prepend('<div class=\'item completed\' id=\''+itemNo+'\'>'+itemText+'</div>');
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Could not complete that at this time");
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#completedItems').on("click", ".completed", function() {
var itemNo = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(itemNo);

var updateQuery = "UPDATE items SET done=0 WHERE itemNo = " + itemNo;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "toDoProcess.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { query: updateQuery, itemNo: itemNo },

        success: function(resultArray){
            if(resultArray != ""){
                var itemNo = resultArray[0]['itemNo'];
                var itemText = resultArray[0]['itemText'];
                $('#' + itemNo).slideUp(function(){
                    $('#needToDo').append('<div class=\'item todo\' id=\''+itemNo+'\'><input type="checkbox">'+itemText+'</div>');
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Could not complete that at this time");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**MY HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1 class="sectionTitle">To Do App</h1>

    <h2 class="sectionTitle">Need to complete</h2>
    <div id="needToDo">
        <?php
        // connect to DB
        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=toDoApp;port=3306","root","root");
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }

        // Query for to-do items 
            // (where items are not marked as done & TO BE ADDED date = selected date)
        // REMEMBER TO ADD WHERE DATE = TODAY etc.

            try {
                $query = $db->query("SELECT itemNo, itemText, needShouldWant FROM items WHERE done != 1 ORDER BY itemNo DESC");
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e;
            }

        // array returned by the query
            // (assigned to result and told to use assoc keys)

            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Each variable in the result array is assigned as item while looping through, each item returns html
            foreach($result as $item){
                $itemNo = $item['itemNo']; ?>
                <div class="item todo" id="<?php echo $itemNo ?>"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox<?php echo $itemNo ?>"><?php echo $item['itemText'];?></div>
            <?}?>
    </div>

    <h2 class="sectionTitle">Completed Items</h2>
    <div id="completedItems">
        <?php
        // Query for to-do items 
            // (where items are not marked as done & TO BE ADDED date = selected date)
        // REMEMBER TO ADD WHERE DATE = TODAY etc.

            try {
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE done = 1 ORDER BY itemNo DESC");
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e;
            }

        // array returned by the query
            // (assigned to result and told to use assoc keys)

            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Each variable in the result array is assigned as item while looping through, each item returns html
            foreach($result as $item){
                $itemNo = $item['itemNo']; ?>
                <div class="item completed" id="<?php echo $itemNo ?>"><?php echo $item['itemText'];?></div>
            <?}?>
    </div>



    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is you are are creating multiple elements with the same id. As a solution try to remove the element once it is hidden using `slideUp`

```
$('#' + itemNo).slideUp(function () {
    $(this).remove()
    $('#completedItems').prepend('<div class=\'item completed\' id=\'' + itemNo + '\'>' + itemText + '</div>');
});
```

.....

```
$('#' + itemNo).slideUp(function () {
    $(this).remove()
    $('#needToDo').append('<div class=\'item todo\' id=\'' + itemNo + '\'><input type="checkbox">' + itemText + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: I suspected it may have been something like that but couldn't quite place my suspicion. This works wonderfully, thank you! (Will mark as answered when allowed).